# Is there a way of overwriting Firebase rules at a lower level in the hierarchy?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my DB I have "users" and those users have a variety of nodes attached to them. I want some nodes to be available, and some to be hidden.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        "dateOfBirth": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
        }, 
        "gender": {
          ".read": "$userId === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
        },
```

The above makes logical sense to me but it doesn't work - the user can't gain access to the "$userId" layer, which it needs to be able to access the rest of the nodes. However, if I add a "read" entry to the "users" level, it overwrites any attempts to deny access at a lower level, for "gender" for example.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
     ".read": true // Added this
      "$userId": {
        "dateOfBirth": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
        }, 
        "gender": {
          ".read": "$userId === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
        },
```

To even reach the dateOfBirth of a different user, their user ID has to be read. So I need to give permission to read the user ID whilst allowing the lower down rules to still take effect.

Comment: Consider splitting your rules into two user-level children - one for public data, and another for private.  You can then write rules to protect them independently.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "two user-level children"? Are you suggesting I split the nodes in my database into private and public folders?

Comment: Yes, but they are called "children" or "nodes", not folders.

Comment: The issue with that solution is that I still don't think it would work - to even access anything inside the private node I would need to read the user ID at the top of the node, which would cause the entire private child to be readable.